# Executing a code block even after catching an exception in Scala

Tags: scala, exception

In my current method, I am trying to make a series of calls and if any of them fail, I want to be able to continue running the remainder (while capturing the Exception that was thrown). I am having a hard time figuring this out in Scala.

So in this example, I want to kick off each of these calls - RunA, RunB and RunC but if RunB throws an exception, I want to print that and continue kicking off RunC after that.

```
var result = Try {
    new RunA()
    new RunB()
    new RunC()
}   catch { 
    case e: Throwable => e.printStackTrace()
    false
 }
```

Outside of having them all individually wrapped in a Try/Catch, I am sure there are better ways to do this which is why I am hoping someone can help with this.

I looked at the 'Ignoring' exception but it appears to completely ignore the exception which I want to atleast log.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't mix `try { ... } catch { ... }` up with `scala.util.Try{ ... }`.

You can

```
import scala.util._
val runA = Try{ new RunA }
val runB = Try{ new RunB }
val runC = Try{ new RunC }
```

and then deal with the exceptions as you see fit.  For instance, if you want to print and continue, you could deal with the try statements right there:

```
def getOrPrint[A](f: => A): Option[A] = Try{ f } match {
  case Success(x) => Some(x)
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace; None
}

getOrPrint{ new RunA }
...
```

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I was looking for. The only problem at this point is that I will have to modify getOrPrint to return a Boolean and then I have to "&&" (as suggested by some others) to aggregate my results. Unfortunately, this leads to a kink in my solution where the moment I fail a test, it returns a false (I had to change the "None" to false) and then it stops executing. There are ways around it so I will try to solve that separately.

Answer (score 2):

There can be more elegant ways for such things with scalaz (e.g. read an article here for some inspiration: http://johnkurkowski.com/posts/accumulating-multiple-failures-in-a-ValidationNEL/), but with "only" Scala you can do something like this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def tryAndLog[T: ClassTag] = Try {
    implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T] // new instance
} match {
    case Success(_) => true
    case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace ; false
}    

def tryRunAll = {
    val A = tryAndLog[RunA]
    val B = tryAndLog[RunB]
    val C = tryAndLog[RunC]
    A && B && C  // returns true if all invocations succeeded, false otherwise
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing scala.util.Try with try {} catch {} which are different concepts. Try wraps function into Success(result) or Failure(error) class, and try-catch is like Java try-catch. I suggest you something like this:

```
  class RunA
  class RunB
  class RunC
  class Result(a: RunA, b: RunB, c: RunC)

  implicit class LogFailure[T](t: Try[T]) {
    def logFailure: Try[T] = t match {
      case scala.util.Failure(err) => err.printStackTrace(); t
      case _ => t
    }
  }

  val tryA= Try(new RunA())
  val tryB= Try(new RunB())
  val tryC = Try(new RunC())

  val result: Try[Result] = for {
    a <- tryA.logFailure
    b <- tryB.logFailure
    c <- tryC.logFailure
  } yield {
    // do smth with a, b, c
    new Result(a, b, c)
  }
```

If A, B, C will be successful you'll get Success(Result) if one of them failure you'll get Failure with first exception, however all of them will be logged (printed stack trace)